# Payment integration in iphone Service App ? which on better to integrate not Apple Inapp

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

i have idea how to implement Payment integration for ios app using in app purchase,but my requirement comes to iphone Service App,as per apple guidelines we must be use inapp purchase and apple take the 30% of every transaction,but my question is any other payment gateway is available for Iphone service app to implement? will apple approved my app if use other payment gateway?please help me out?how to solve the issue.if integrate paypalSdk will apple approved my app?if i integrate webview payment will my app approved
?

Help me out from the issue. thanks and Regards

Comment: Any one have idea how to implement

Comment: Have you got your app approved by implementing the payment gateway and used dynamic pricing?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through apple review guidelines and your doubts will be cleared.

You can use third party payment gateway,if you are offering physical goods,service outside app. If you are selling your content or service inside app then you must use inapp-purchase.

As per [purchasing currencies guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies),

1. Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected.
2. Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the App

Regrding your questions, answers are as below

1. You can't use third party payment gateway to provide credits which are using in app.
2. Yes there is most probably chance of rejection if you implement third party payment gateway instead of IAP to sell your content or service inside app .

You may read [Apple review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Rhual Patel,but i have review the Apple review guidelines and if i use inapp purchase no dynamic price,so that is way i'm going to other gateway.